# Can I boot a live Linux image from my D partition?

Tags: linux, boot, partitioning

I am running Windows 10, I created a partition D of 8GB size on the same hard drive.
I have downloaded an .iso image of a live linux distribution, can I make my D partition bootable in order to boot Linux ? If so how ? My laptop is from 2020 so it is probably UEFI.
I would like to do that without USB

Comment: Yes, you can, but you can not install Linux into the D: partition, rather you install Linux to empty disk space, because Windows uses NTFS and Linux uses ext4. You need to delete the partition. After that, use either EasyBCD to create a boot entry for the .iso, or use VMWare to create a virtual machine and boot the .iso, then you can install Linux to your disk and let it do the partitioning for you.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately most options in add entry are greyed out in easyBCD including adding a Linux entry. It seems to be a Microsoft limitation...

Comment: Then you need to disable UEFI boot, you can find the needed registry hacks via Googling, EasyBCD doesn't work with UEFI boot.